# why the error thrown from callable cloud function does not trigger on failure listener?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

so I have callable cloud function like this:

```
exports.verifiedUserDeactivateTheEvent = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const eventID = data.eventID
    const verifiedUserID = context.auth.uid

   try {

    // check user
    const verifiedUserDocumentSnapshot = await db.doc(`users/${verifiedUserID}`).get()

    if (!verifiedUserDocumentSnapshot.exists || verifiedUserDocumentSnapshot.data().verified === false) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Invalid User', 'Invalid User')
    }

    // rest of the code

    return "success"


  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    return error.message
  }



})
```

if the user is invalid or unauthorized then it will throw httpsError message 'Invalid User'

I use this in callable function in my Android app

```
fun verifiedUserDeactivateTheEvent(eventID: String) : Task<String> {

    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    val data = hashMapOf(
        "eventID" to eventID
    )


    return functions
        .getHttpsCallable("verifiedUserDeactivateTheEvent")
        .call(data)
        .continueWith { task ->
            val result = task.result?.data as String
            result
        }


}
```

and use it like this

```
verifiedUserDeactivateTheEvent(selectedEvent.eventID).addOnSuccessListener {
    toast(it) // the error message will be shown in here
}.addOnFailureListener {
    toast(it.localizedMessage) // not in here
}
```

I expect that error message will be shown on `onFailureListener`, but that error string message is still shown in `onSuccessListener`. I need to set different actions if an error is exist or not

how to make the https error thrown from callable function will be shown in `onFailureListener` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation for [HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror), the error code must be one of the ones listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.html#functionserrorcode).  Your choices are:

> "ok" | "cancelled" | "unknown" | "invalid-argument" |
>   "deadline-exceeded" | "not-found" | "already-exists" |
>   "permission-denied" | "resource-exhausted" | "failed-precondition" |
>   "aborted" | "out-of-range" | "unimplemented" | "internal" |
>   "unavailable" | "data-loss" | "unauthenticated"

These map to HTTP error response codes, which determines how the client will process the response.

Try using "permission-denied" instead if "Invalid User":

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Invalid User')
```

Comment: sir I am sorry but it seems it still not trigger `onFailureListener` here is the logcat on my android https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNMmq.png , and here is the error log in cloud function after using 'permission-denied' https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QOfO.png